# Best way to Sort Python Dictionary by number of same Values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
input = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'b', 5:'c', 6:'b'}
```

a - 1 time

b - 3 times

c - 2 times

I want to sort the dictionary in such a way that the value which repeats maximum times will come at fist followed by the value which repeats second most times and so on...

Desired Output

```
output = {1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'a'}
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary. Maybe with collections.OrderedDict. but let's see your attempts first.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edited for Python 3 compatibility.

```
from collections import Counter
i = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'b', 5:'c', 6:'b'}
print (Counter(i.values()))

#Output
Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
```

Comment: How the hell is that an accepted answer, given that it's nowhere near desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

input = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'b', 5: 'c', 6: 'b'}
output = {index: value for index, (value, _)
                       in enumerate(Counter(input.values()).most_common(),
                                    start=1)}
print(output)
```

Comment: enumerate takes additional argument, `start` - it may be used to initialize counter to 1.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski: sure, why not. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to realize you do not even care about input dict keys, only about input dict values.

```
real_input = input.values()
```

Second of all, you need to count occurences:

```
counted_items = collections.Counter(real_input)
```

Third of all, you want to iterate over them in order from most common to least common. `.most_common()` returns list of (key, count) tuples in expected order.

```
most_common_in_order = counted_items.most_common()
```

After that you want to convert that list to dict, with consecutive inegers as keys

```
result = {i: v for i, (v, _) in zip(itertools.count(1), most_common_in_order)}
```

Or, in concise form:

```
result = {i: v for i, (v, _) in zip(itertools.count(1), 
                                    collections.Counter(input.values()).most_common())}
```

Note that dictionaries are inherently not ordered, so actual order is implementation detail, and it's not guaranteed.